# Comparing two lists and removing duplicates from one

Tags: java, collections, duplicates, equals

I have an object called FormObject that contains two ArrayLists - oldBooks and newBooks - both of which contain Book objects.

oldBooks is allowed to contain duplicate Book objects
newBooks is not allowed to contain duplicate Book objects within itself and cannot include any duplicates of Book objects in the oldBooks list.

The definition of a duplicate Book is complex and I can't override the equals method as the definition is not universal across all uses of the Book object.

I plan to have a method on the FormObject class called removeDuplicateNewBooks which will perform the above functionality.

How would you go about implementing this? My first thought was to use HashSets to eliminate the duplicates but not being able to override equals on the Book object means it won't work.

Comment: So, how are you checking for book equality atm?

Comment: If you know logic to determine duplicates, Then you should be able to override equals method using same logic.

Comment: If the definition of equality for books is not universal, how will you universally decide if books are duplicates? How is it different defining it overriding equals than defining it some other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [`TreeSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Comparator%29) with a custom `Comparator<Book>`:

- construct the `TreeSet` with a `Comparator` implementing the custom logic you want
- use `set.addAll(bookList)`

Now the `Set` contains only unique books.

Comment: I thought about this, but it felt 'wrong' to use a comparator as semantically they're supposed to be used for sorting objects, not testing an alternative definition of equality..

Comment: True, but the contract is that a comparator returns 0 if and only if the objects are equal, so it implies equality testing.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. This is definitely the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

For making the new books unique:

Create a wrapper class around Book and declare it's equals / hashCode methods based on the enclosed book object:

```
public class Wrapper{

    private final Book book;

    public Wrapper(final Book book){
        assert book != null;
        this.book = book;
    }

    public Book getBook(){
        return this.book;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object other){
        return other instanceof Wrapper ? 
            Arrays.equals(
                this.getBookInfo(),
                ((Wrapper) other).getBookInfo()
            ) : false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return Arrays.hashCode(this.getBookInfo());
    }

    private String[] getBookInfo(){
        return new String[] { 
            this.book.getAuthor(), 
            this.book.getTitle(), 
            this.book.getIsbn() 
        };
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**
Optimized equals and hashCode and fixed a bug in hashCode.

Now use a set to remove duplicates:

```
Set<Wrapper> wrappers = new HashSet<Wrapper>();
for(Book book: newBooks){
    wrappers.add(new Wrapper(book);
}
newBooks.clear();
for(Wrapper wrapper: wrappers){
    newBooks.add(wrapper.getBook());
}
```

(But of course the TreeSet answer with the custom comparator is more elegant because you can use the Book class itself)

**EDIT:**
(removed reference to apache commons because my improved equals / hashCode methods are better)

Comment: Hmm, this is an interesting solution, definitely not something I would have thought of.

Answer (score 1):

[HashingStrategy](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/blob/master/eclipse-collections-api/src/main/java/org/eclipse/collections/api/block/HashingStrategy.java) is the concept you're looking for. It's a strategy interface that allows you to define custom implementations of equals and hashcode.

```
public interface HashingStrategy<E>
{
    int computeHashCode(E object);
    boolean equals(E object1, E object2);
}
```

[Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) includes hash tables as well as iteration patterns based on hashing strategies. First, you'd create your own `HashingStrategy` to answer whether two `Books` are equal.

Next, you'd use `distinct()` to remove duplicates within `newBooks` and a `UnifiedSetWithHashingStrategy` to eliminate duplicates across the lists.

```
List<Book> oldBooks = ...;
List<Book> newBooks = ...;
HashingStrategy<Book> hashingStrategy = new HashingStrategy() { ... };
Set<Book> set = UnifiedSetWithHashingStrategy<>(hashingStrategy, oldBooks);
List<Book> result = ListIterate.distinct(newBooks, hashingStrategy).reject(set::contains);
```

The `distinct()` method returns only the unique items according to the hashing strategy. It returns a list, not a set, preserving the original order. The call to `reject()` returns another new list without the elements that the set contains, according to the same hashing strategy.

If you can change newBooks to implement an Eclipse Collections interface, then you can call the `distinct()` method directly.

```
MutableList<Book> newBooks = ...;
MutableList<Book> result = newBooks.distinct(hashingStrategy).reject(oldBooks::contains);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.